# Is it possible to write an expression-bodied member containing an if statement?

Tags: c#, if-statement, expression-bodied-members

I wonder if it is possible to rewrite the following method using an expression-bodied member:

```
private void Checkup()
{
   if (errorCondition) throw new InvalidOperationException("Error");
}
```

Comment: have you tried it?

Comment: Sure. And I have not been able. But just wondering if there is any escamotage to do it. It's just a curiosity.

Comment: Any solution to make the code compile is going to involve way more code than the 2 characters you need to type out (or one depending on your autocomplete settings) for the statement block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I have found a solution:

```
void Checkup() => _ = condition ? throw new InvalidOperationException("Error") : 0;
```